# JSF/Primefaces How to include an .xhtml from another domain into your .xhtml

Tags: templates, primefaces, xhtml, include

I am trying to include an xhtml which is on another domain (on the same server) inside my .xhtml.

The sample code is the following

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" target="body" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:layout id="page" fullPage="true">
            <!-- North -->
            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="10%"
                style="border: none !important">
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <!-- South -->
            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="5%" collapsible="true" gutter="0">
                <h:outputText value="South unit Content." />
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <!-- West -->
            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Menu"
                collapsible="true" effect="slide" styleClass="menuBar">
                <h:form id="form1">
                    <p:panelMenu>
                        <p:submenu label="Students">
                            <p:menuitem value="page1" update=":centerpanel"
                                actionListener="#{layoutController.setNavigation('page2.xhtml')}" />
                            <p:menuitem value="page2" update=":centerpanel"
                                actionListener="#{layoutController.setNavigation('http://localhost:8080/externalsite/newpage.xhtml')}" />
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:panelMenu>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <!-- Center -->
            <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
                <h:panelGroup id="centerpanel" layout="block">
                    <ui:include id="include" src="#{layoutController.navigation}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

So basically in the center layout unit I am trying to include the external .xhtml (which is on the same domain however).

Comment: You mean: include `web content` or code ?

Comment: Well, my purpose is to include a ready made webapp which is on another domain, and build a menu around it (and other apps). The idea was to include it like the code above, which essentially means including the code from the external .xhtml into my own correct? If there's an easier way to do that I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I don't know your system design, but AFAIK it's impossible !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSF templates can be included only, if they are available within the same classloader.

If you want to embed an external page into your page, you need to user **iframe**.

For example:

```
<iframe src="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf"/>
```

allows you to embed PrimeFaces showcase withing your page.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. With the `ui:include` Tag you can only include Code Snippets from other xhtml files. What you are trying to do is accessing Code from another domain, but what you see in the final web app is only the generated HTML and Javascript Code. You cannot work with that in your application, as you have no access to the sourcecode.